# joined values from two tables with SQL but PHP does not show value on table

Tags: php, sql

Sory to bother but I am loosing too much time on this: My sql query returns the table as I want it to, but for some reason I cannot get the result to appear on the table.

My SQL code:

```
$ssql = "SELECT * FROM tickets
JOIN (SELECT agencias.pais_id, paises.pais_nombre, agencias.EMP_CODE FROM agencias JOIN      paises ON paises.pais_id = agencias.pais_id) agpais
ON tickets.cod_emp = agpais.EMP_CODE
WHERE tipo='NUE' ORDER BY id_ticket DESC" . $criterio;
$rs = mysql_query($ssql);
$total_registros = mysql_num_rows($rs);
```

PHP HTML code:

```
<?php
while($resz = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {  ?>
<td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#C2DBE7"><font face="Verdana, Arial,            Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1" color="#000000"> $resz[pais_nombre]</font></td>

<?php
} 
?>
```

var_dump($rs) returns: resource(18) of type (mysql result)

Comment: Please report your error message or the var_dump($rs)

Comment: The `mysql` extension has been deprecated and will be removed in future versions of `PHP`, [using `mysqli` or `PDO` is recommended](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: What's in `$criterio`?

Comment: criteria probably limit 0,10 or something

Comment: @Dave, good point. I was wondering if there was a space at the beginning or not in case it broke the query

Comment: @joseph4tw indeed could also be missing the space so its showing as DESCLIMIT.  Would be nice if he could post the result of echo $ssql for us to check

Comment: var_dump($rs) returns "resource(18) of type (mysql result)"

Comment: just realised its a subselect as the origin table of a join oO thats never going to work surely. `JOIN (SELECT agencias.pais_id, paises.pais_nombre, agencias.EMP_CODE FROM agencias JOIN paises ON paises.pais_id = agencias.pais_id) agpais ON tickets.cod_emp = agpais.EMP_CODE` you're returning 3 items as an object and assigning them to agpais and then expecting it to do a join against an object oO never going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
while($resz = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {  ?>
<td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#C2DBE7">
    <font face="Verdana, Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1" color="#000000">
         <?php echo $resz['pais_nombre'];>?
    </font>
</td>

<?php
} 
?>
```

If you specify something in html which is php code you have to put them in the php tags.That you forget to do and

```
<?php
//Php code goes here
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$resz[pais_nombre]` requires single quotes around it like this `$resz['pais_nombre']`

It also needs PHP tags around it so `<?php echo $resz['pais_nombre']; ?>`

Comment: I am using " <<<HTML and HTML; " for generating all html code with php and for some reason it gives me an error when using single quotes but even if I put $resz['pais_nombre']; into a variable it does not show the data... no error is thrown.